# Python - counting duplicate strings

Tags: python, duplicates, counting

I'm trying to write a function that will count the number of word duplicates in a string and then return that word if the number of duplicates exceeds a certain number (n). Here's what I have so far:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def repeat_word_count(text, n):
  words = text.split()
  tally = defaultdict(int)
  answer = []

  for i in words:
    if i in tally:
      tally[i] += 1
    else:
      tally[i] = 1
```

I don't know where to go from here when it comes to comparing the dictionary values to n.

How it should work: 
repeat_word_count("one one was a racehorse two two was one too", 3) should return ['one']

Comment: Do you want a `dictionary`  as an output with the `key` is the `count` and the `value` the word? Is that what you are trying to get? So, if there is a word with no duplicates the the `key` would be `1` and if there are duplicates the `key` will be the number for how many duplicates there are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
from collections import defaultdict
tally = defaultdict(int)
text = "one two two three three three"
for i in text.split():
    tally[i] += 1
print tally  # defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'three': 3, 'two': 2, 'one': 1})
```

Putting this in a function:

```
def repeat_word_count(text, n):
    output = []
    tally = defaultdict(int) 
    for i in text.split():
        tally[i] += 1
    for k in tally:
      if tally[k] > n:
          output.append(k)
    return output

text = "one two two three three three four four four four"
repeat_word_count(text, 2)
Out[141]: ['four', 'three']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
for i in words:
    tally[i] = tally.get(i, 0) + 1
```

instead of

```
for i in words:
    if i in tally:
         tally[words] += 1 #you are using words the list as key, you should use i the item
    else:
         tally[words] = 1
```

If you simply want to count the words, use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) would fine.

```
>>> import collections
>>> a = collections.Counter("one one was a racehorse two two was one too".split())
>>> a
Counter({'one': 3, 'two': 2, 'was': 2, 'a': 1, 'racehorse': 1, 'too': 1})
>>> a['one']
3
```

Comment: That worked for the tallying issue - thanks! Do you have any suggestions for how I should go about tackling the rest?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a `dictionary` counting the words in a string, you can try this:

```
string = 'hello world hello again now hi there hi world'.split()
d = {}
for word in string:
    d[word] = d.get(word, 0) +1
print d
```

Output:

```
{'again': 1, 'there': 1, 'hi': 2, 'world': 2, 'now': 1, 'hello': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

As luoluo says, use collections.Counter.

To get the item(s) with the highest tally, use the [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method with argument `1`, which returns a list of pairs `(word, tally)` whose 2nd coordinates are all the same max tally. If the "sentence" is nonempty then that list is too. So, the following function returns *some* word that occurs at least `n` times if there is one, and returns `None` otherwise:

```
from collections import Counter

def repeat_word_count(text, n):
    if not text: return None        # guard against '' and None!
    counter = Counter(text.split())
    max_pair = counter.most_common(1)[0]
    return max_pair[0] if max_pair[1] > n else None
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use **Counter class** for that case:

```
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter(text.split())
```

Where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values. Then it's easy to keep the words that exceeds your n number with iterkeys() in a for loop like

```
list=[]
for k in cnt.iterkeys():
    if cnt[k]>n:
        list.append(k)
```

In list you'll got your list of words.

**Edited: sorry, thats if you need many words, BrianO have the right one for your case.

Comment: And I think yours is the best way to get all words whose frequency exceeds n. But you can just say `for k in cnt`, no need for `.iterkeys()`.

Comment: Thanks, and could be in a list comprehension then just return `[k for k in cnt if cnt[k] > n]` although it's little less clear.

Comment: Yep that's what I'd do. I think it's a little *more* clear, actually :) but that's me.